# Automated password generation based on logged in facebook account

Tags: iphone, facebook, xmpp

I'm working on an iPhone application which requires a user to login to Facebook. However that is only to retrieve a  users friendslist, after that I wish to continue communication through my own XMPP server, I would like to automate the account creation to this server.

For this I would need a username, which is pretty straighforward: the facebook user id, however I would also need to create a password based on some sort of private key showing the user has logged in to Facebook. This key should be the same for any device logged in over any amount of time, I've been looking at the Facebook API but could only find an access token, which I believe is different when the user logs in from a different device.

My question: Is there anything available from the Facebook API with these requirements? Any suggestions for alternative solutions would be welcome too.

Thanks!

Edit:

Example:

1. User uses the app for the first time on his iPhone, logs in with facebook and the app automatically creates an acount on my XMPP server, where the user ID is equal to the facebook ID and the password is something that shows the user has been logged into his facebook account.
2. Now the user uses the app on his iPad, again logging into his facebook account, however already having an account on my XMPP server the same password must be generated from the data received from facebook.

Step 2 is the part which poses a problem for me, I need data that shows that the user has been logged into his account, and which is the same wherever and whenever he logs in, just so that the same password can be generated every time. I believe that if I use the access_token for this then this will change if the user for example doesn't log in for 60 days and starts using the app again, or maybe even when he logs into a different device?

To clarify: the XMPP server that Facebook offers is not to my needs, I need to be able to send other things besides chat messages and also need to be able to store messages so that new devices which log on can be synced to a proper state.

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook XMPP, I recommend you to use the custom SASL mechanism called X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM. Basically, the user must first log in to your application and grant the xmpp_login extended permission. Follow the client side flow to get a valid access_token for the user with the xmpp_login extended permission.

You send an base64 encoded string over TLS with the following parmeters:

```
string method: Should be the same as the method specified by the server.
string api_key: The application key associated with the calling application.
string access_token: The access_token obtained in the above step.
float call_id: The request's sequence number.
string v: This must be set to 1.0 to use this version of the API.
string format: Optional - Ignored.
string cnonce: Optional - Client-selected nonce. Ignored.
string nonce: Should be the same as the nonce specified by the server.
```

Your appID (api_key) can be use in multiple context and you'll be able to get the user access token for each of the user's devices.

Here is the Chat API doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Comment: Isn't that a mechanism just to login to facebook? I may have misunderstood, but how would this work to create a password to my own XMPP server? (See the example in my edit).

Comment: I believe you can store the access_token for the user and re-auth the user each time the user comes back to your app. You will update the access_token if it's more than 60 days old.
The oAuth Dialog is not prompt to the user if he didn't deauthorized your app in his settings. So you will get a fresh access_token for this user.
If you need to sync the device with fresh data with your server you can generate your own password which will be valid if the user successfully authenticate within Facebook as the user is identified.
hope this helps.

Comment: Yes but is there anything I can use as input from facebook for generating the password? Something that will be the same no matter when or where the users logs in. When the user decides to log on from another device then the app must know the password of the user to my server. My problem is with the password generation, what parameters that facebook sends me can I use that will be the same throughout Facebook's lifetime?